# Is it possible to nest transactions in peewee + sqlite?

Tags: python, sqlite, transactions, peewee

Executing the code below produces unexpected results. Is it a problem with peewee, sqlite, or my understanding of transactions?

The code creates a transaction, then calls 3 times a function that creates 3 records in its own transaction. The function succeeds the 1st and 3rd time, but it fails the 2nd.

I would expect to find 6 records in the database, 3 created at the 1st call and 3 created at the 3rd, and the records created during the 2nd call would be rolled back.

Instead I find only the records created at the 3rd call.

```
import peewee

class DbTest(peewee.Model):
    test = peewee.CharField()
    class Meta:
        database = db

def test(txt):
    with db.transaction():
        DbTest.create(test=txt + '1')
        DbTest.create(test=txt + '2')
        if txt == 'b':
            raise
        DbTest.create(test=txt + '3')

DbTest().drop_table(True)
DbTest().create_table(True)

with db.transaction():
    for txt in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
        try:
            test(txt)
        except:
            pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to nest transactions, you can use savepoints [doc link](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Database.savepoint).

```
with db.transaction():
    with db.savepoint():
        do_stuff()
    with db.savepoint():
        do_more_stuff()
```

Comment: Is there a way to know if I'm inside a transaction? That is, how can a function that needs to create its own transaction (like the `test()` on the question) know whether to use `db.savepoint()` (because a transaction has been created before the function was called) or `db.transaction()` (because no transaction has been created yet)?

Comment: You can call `db.transaction_depth()`.

Comment: Thanks. I tried with `with db.savepoint() if db.transaction_depth() else db.transaction():` and it worked. Then I tried substituting `transaction` with `savepoint` to my original code and it works too. It looks like I can just not open the transaction, and just use `with db.savepoint()` blocks. Is that correct/safe?

Comment: I'm not sure...I had thought savepoints could only be created in transactions.